# Angular TypeScript Best Practice

Tags: angular, typescript

How are people generally checking Angular/TypeScript code ... with or without the end-of-line ";"

I'm watching a video online and this developer isn't using the end-of-line (end of statement) syntax.

I don't see anything "best practices" gospel on this... suggestions?  Accepted practices?

Comment: it doesn't matter. it's up to preference. some style guides include it, some don't. pick one and use an extension on your IDE to enforce it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of taste. There are various opinionated styleguides e.g. https://github.com/airbnb/javascript. Check https://angular.io/guide/styleguide for angular styleguide.

Typescript compiles with both, existing and non-existing semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

İf you are using Visual Studio, check out *ESLint* extention by Dirk Baeumer. It autocorrects most of the syntax automatically

Answer (score 1):

In my organization, as most are Java developers, we follow the convention of **keeping the semicolon** as in Java it's mandatory to use it. As @Mursal mentioned there is an VS Code extension ([ESLint](https://eslint.org/)) that can help you to autofix that, although you need to have defined a eslint.json configuration file including the rules. 
So it's upon to your team/you to see what is more appropriate for you.